# In-App Purchase (ios/android) How to Offer Local Payments?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, in-app-billing

I know most people in North America have credit cards, so the issue i'm asking may not be relevant.

But what about in developing countries such as Indonesia where most people still don't have credit cards. I'm thinking of developing an app, where i think it falls into app that must use in-app purchase and not third party local payment gateways that support ATM/bank transfers.

Is it allowed by apple appstore / android playstore to add third party payment gateways to facilitate those users who don't have credit cards?

Answer (score 0):

Review this link for in-app purchase design guidelines.

https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase

> If you want to unlock features or functionality within your app, (by
>   way of example: subscriptions, in-game currencies, game levels, access
>   to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you must use in-app
>   purchase.

You can use third party only if you are selling goods which are not in above criteria, there is no option to check if user has credit card or not.

Users from selected countries can pay via mobile phone billing for in-app purchases. Refer to this link for allowed carriers and countries for phone billing option

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT205102